# CSS setting to force 300PPI when saving as PDF

Tags: css

I've got the following css setting:

```
@media print {  
  @page {
    size: 5700px 3900px; /* landscape 19" x 13" A0 */
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

This is so that, when I save the page as a PDF, it saves it at 300PPI. When I actually export it as a PDF though, Chrome exports it with a resolution of `4275px 2925px` which is only 225PPI.

Is there a style I can add to force exporting in 300PPI? i.e. as `5700px 3900px`

Comment: You are aware that the `@page { size: }` property is not widely supported? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: Nope, I'm new to CSS. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: AFAIK, "Save as PDF" does not apply `print` media rules. You have to use the Print-to-PDF option in Chrome.

Comment: I think it does? Changing the styles in `print` affects the resolution albeit at a .75x ratio

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a style I can add to force exporting in 300PPI

No, there is not. That's not what CSS is for. CSS is concerned with creating a layout from a structured document and applying visual effects *given the constraints of the rendering device*, thus CSS does not define those constraints - instead it works with them.

Anyway, when writing a `media print` stylesheet, don't use `px` units, [instead use CSS's `mm`, `cm`, `in` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

As ISO A0 paper is 841x1189mm then use this:

```
@media print {  
  @page {
    size: 1189mm 841mm;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Dai! I tried it but it just made it smaller unfortunately (`3370 x 2382` was exported)

Comment: @LorenzoAng How are you generating the PDF in Chrome? Are you using Chrome's built-in PDF generator or going via Adobe' PDF printer? Do you have any zoom or scaling options set? Is A0 set as the page size there too?

Comment: Yep, just printing and then selecting "save as PDF". And yes, paper is set to A0

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but instead Chrome 87 crashed on me when I tried to do a Print Preview - fun.

Comment: Thanks anyway Dai. 225PPI it is for now I guess.